# get value from ajax to be submitted on form action

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Please help me on my code i want to get the selected value on my ajax_details.php so that it will be submitted on my form action process_details.php here is my code:

**injury_details.php**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function injury_nature_change(){
$.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"ajax_details.php",
         data:{
             allvals:$("#nature_id").val(),
             },
         success:function(msg){
             $("#div").html(msg);
             }});
}
</script>
<form method="post" action="process_details.php">
<table border="2">
<tr><th colspan="2">Injury Details</th></tr>
<tr><td>
<select id="nature_id" name="injury_nature" onChange="injury_nature_change()">
<option><--select--></option>
<option value="1">Musculoskeletal Injuries</option>
<option value="2">Soft Tissue Injuries</option>
<option value="3">Illnesses</option>
<option value="4">Other Injuries</option>
</select>
</td>
<td><div id="div"></div></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="add" />
</form>
```

**ajax_details.php**

```
<select name=injury_details_under><?php
$id = $_POST['allvals'];
$sql="SELECT value_name FROM tbl_injury_nature WHERE value_nature_id=$id";
$res=mysql_query($sql) or die("error:".mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $value_name = $row['value_name'];
    echo"<option value='$value_name'>$value_name</option>";
}
    ?>
</select>
```

**process_details.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$injury_nature = $_POST['injury_nature'];
$injury_nature_under = $_POST['injury_nature_under'];
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_injury (injury,under) VALUES  ('$injury_nature','$injury_nature_under')";
$res=mysql_query($sql) or die("error:".mysql_error());
}
?>
```

thanks for the future help..

> This whole code actually works thanks for everybody's help..

Comment: you need to give your `<select>` a name value on the ajax_details.php page or it won't be submitted. Change it to `<select name="injury_nature_under">`

Comment: oh im sorry.. i had actually copied wrong.. yes i had put name on my select.. but when i submit in the database it sets blank..

Comment: Okay - you updated it to `injury_details_under` but are trying to grab it using `injury_nature_under` - if it's not another copy error, that could be the issue.

Comment: @Krishna I edited your title. You cannot mark your own question as `[SOLVED]`. SO would have made the change anyway. Either you enter an answer yourself and mark it as answered.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thank you for the advice.. i want to apologize cause im new here in stackoverflow.com i dont know the rules.. thanks a lot

Comment: @Krishna No need to apologize, and you're welcome. And welcome to SO, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not defining `$injury_nature_under` in the form, are you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might mistake something here:

- if you try to post a form to backend using regular `form`, then you extract it by using the `name` attribute specified by html form elements, eg. `injury_nature`
- if you use jQuery ajax to post your data to backend, you extract it by using the object name specified in `data` option, in your case `allvals`

See if this solves your problem.